# 1000s of Inactive session in Oracle

Tags: asp.net, oracle, hibernate

There are 1000s of Inactive sessions are there in Oracle database. Some are even 1 month old. sql_text shows a particular query in 90% of the cases. Query is working fine without any slowness.OracleConnection is disposed properly.

Any idea what can be reason ?

Query used to find inactive sessions

```
SELECT s.SID, s.STATUS, s.process, s.osuser, a.sql_text, p.program
FROM v$session s, v$sqlarea a, v$process p
WHERE s.PREV_HASH_VALUE = a.hash_value
    AND s.PREV_SQL_ADDR = a.address 
    AND s.paddr = p.addr 
    AND s.STATUS = 'INACTIVE'
```

Comment: Have you checked your middleware/application connection pool settings?  Some people think more connections = faster, which can lead to a ridiculous number of connections.

Comment: It is a hibernate call. 
There are 1000s of Inactive sessions. 
Why system is not re-using the inactive sessions?
Whay System is creating new sessions every time and leaving them inactive.
Some sessions are even 1 month old as well.

Application code
--------------------
//NHibernate transaction class
namespace NHibernate
{
 public interface ITransaction : IDisposable
{
}
}


//tx is nHibernate's  ITransaction object

try
{
  if (tx != null && !tx.WasCommitted && !tx.WasRolledBack)
   {
     tx.Commit();
   }
}
finally()
{
   tx.dispose();
}